# For your [reviews]

Tags: discussion, clean-up, meta-tags

I draw your attention to the tag [reviews](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reviews).

There is no tag description, and no usage guidance.

This looks like another classic "meta tag". It has no context without the other tags on a question and seems to be used for different things.

Currently, 7 questions with the tag:

- 2 are about reviews on Google+
- 1 is about simultaneously adding a photo to reviews on Foodspotting, Google Local, *and* Yelp
- 2 are about Amazon.com reviews
- 1 is a closed "help me find an app" question
- 1 is a "help me find an app" that's currently still open

Comment: @sathya: Is it a new SOP to mark "burninate in progress" questions on meta as `status-planned`?

Comment: we use that over at [su], thought might as well use it here :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now complete - all [reviews](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reviews) have been removed.

Comment: Unfortunately, a question author disagreed with the removal of the tag, and re-created [tag:review].

Comment: [tag:review] seems no more useful than [tag:reviews].  Perhaps that should be added to the burn list.